# How to access docker container using aws public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

I installed Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 AWS Server, and enabled ufw on Ubuntu server. Allowed Port 80 and 443. Then created a docker nginx container. The docker container is running, but i am unable to access it on other machine using AWS public ip. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, you do not need to play UFW in case of AWS instance. you better to control firewall related thing in [AWS EC2 security group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html).

so follow these steps

- Allow 80 from the security group of EC2 instance
- Publish port `80` from the container i.e `docker run -dit -p 80:80 nginx:alpine`
- Verify instance is in public subnet and reachable from the internet

If not work by doing the above step, then

- do ssh to the instance
- check using `curl localhost`

if the response on localhost inside Instance then one reason might be that the instance is in private subnet and you can not access private instance from public.

Comment: Hey man, how do you verify if you have a public subnet?

Comment: incase of the public subnet, your instance should respond on public IP. or simply if doing ssh directly from your local machine its in public subnet

Answer (score 0):

change security groups inbound rules

Custom TCP in port range 8080 and source 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.
Use host networking mode: By default, Docker containers use a bridge network that may result in the container being assigned a different IP address. You can switch to the host networking mode by adding the `--network host` option when running the container. For example:

docker run --network host <image_name>