# Assigning IP Address to Docker Container on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-ecr

I am currently trying to get my docker container to be publicly addressable so I can route it through aws route 53 (DNS). I have my contained on an ubuntu ec2 and am looking for what I should do next. Here is the screenshot of my containers running on the instance.

[image]

Should I try to route these through nginx like normal or can I point them directly to an IP address through something like elastic IP on aws. Thank you!

Comment: Try this too, in my case it works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366411/how-to-access-docker-container-using-aws-public-ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static public IP for your instance, [elastic ip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) should be used.

To ensure connectivity to your docker containers, please double check:

- if **security group(s)** on the instance allow inbound traffic to the ports of interest.
- same, please check **network ACL** on your subnet if they do not block the connections - both inbound and outbound.
- ensure that the instance is in a **public subnet** and is reachable from the internet.
- check if you can connect to the containers from inside of the instance, to make sure that your **application is working** as expected

Alternatively, if you do not want to manage the instance and docker yourself, you can look into using [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) or [Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) which will greatly simply management of your containers.

Comment: Additionally deploying the container on ECS will be a better option.

Comment: @ShubhamJain Thanks. I will add that next to Fargate.